# subclassing views, handling self iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, subclass, self

I'm getting a build error in the following:

```
[self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

because self isn't applicable in the subclass. I'm essentially subclassing a subclass because I only want to call tweetViewController if a series of if statements are correct.

How do I handle 'self' in a subclass without importing all the other classes I want to call this subclass from?

Comment: is self a UIViewController subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are subclassing UIViewController then you just need to call the super's implementation:

```
[super presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
[super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: After trying super, I get this error:
 Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'NSObject' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:'

Comment: Then I refer you back to Cyprians question: is self a UIViewController subclass?

Comment: I changed it to a view controller subclass, and I don't get the build error. But it still won't present or dismiss on self or super

Comment: If you change an objects class like that then you need to go back through your code and outlets and whatnot and make sure they are expecting this object to be of this class. Also, use the debugger and step through the part where you present the view controller to see if your variables are being set correctly.